# Add multiple blank lines to a Report from TextBox?

Tags: sql, ms-access, crystal-reports

I have an Access Database linked to a Crystal Report (2011). The Report has many Sections, one Group, as well as several Sub Reports.

Each Sub Report is in its own Section on the main Report. Each Section/Sub Report is set to "Keep together on one page."

What my boss is looking for is a way to add space "on-demand" to the end of any section. In other words, he wants the report to be a word document that he can freely add lines to.

I know this is not exactly possible. I do realize that you can export a Report as a .doc File, but that takes extra steps and we are trying to automate this as much as possible.

What I am considering is a TextBox (TextBox1) in Access that allows you to type in a number and adding a that number of blank lines to a different TextBox (TextBox2) (E.g. if you type 3 in TextBox1 then the value for TextBox2 would be something like "". Then referencing TextBox2 in a formula in the Report using HTML interpretation.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Does anyone have any better suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already, I'd try giving him/her a version of the report with "extra" blank space already included.  Another option might be doing page breaks after the sub-reports.  Make sure it looks good to you and then present it.

But, to do the variable blank spaces, I'd use a Crystal parameter (or multiple Crystal parameters).  This way, everything is in one place.  If the boss decides there should be one more line, he/she can just hit refresh and change the parameter rather than going back to the Access form.  Once you have the parameter, add a formula to the form when you want the variable spaces, and set it to "can grow".  The actual formula would be something like:

```
Local NumberVar i;
Local StringVar out := "";

for i := 1 to {?BlankLines} do
    out := out + chr(13) + chr(10);

out;
```

Comment: Well, the space that he needs to add is different for each section, that is why I have to give him the choice. Can you explain how to do it in Access?

Comment: @ZLHysong I had a feeling the already formatted report wouldn't fly.  I'm not very good with Access, it sounded like you had a pretty good handle on that side of it.  My suggestion was to NOT use Access to control the size of the blank space, but to use Crystal parameters instead.  That way the tweaking of the spacing is done by hitting refresh, rather than doing data entry in Access and re-generating.

Comment: To do it with Access, you'd add the text values to the form (also with "can grow" set).

Comment: Yeah, no I get that. The issue is that we have upwards of 25 Sections, each needing a different amount of spacing. I don't know how that would work in a Crystal Reports setting.

Comment: @ZLHysong Crystal or Access, either way you need to identify what setting goes with what section of the report. "Text_Box_Section1", "Text_Box_Section2", etc vs. "Blank Lines Section 1", "Blank Lines Section 2", etc -- both are ugly, and you need 25+ either way. Access would be 25+ text boxes, Crystal would be 25+ parameters.

Comment: Except that I am the only person with Crystal Reports. Everyone else will just be using a viewer, and in Access it would simply be easier. he does not have to go through 25+ parameters each and every time he opens the report, he can adjust as needed then leave it be. So can you help me set it up in Access? Just something to get me started, then I'll be good on my own.

Comment: @ZLHysong Sorry, I'm not very familiar with Access. But, I can say that once you have the field in Access, you would add that field to the report where the spaces would go.  You may need to split the section, with the sub-report in the original, and the spacers in the new section below.  By the way: parameters work fine in the Crystal viewer.